# How to evaluate $x^2+iy^2$ on the line from 1 to i?

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to evaluate $$\int_\gamma f$$, where $f(x+yi) = x^2 + iy^2$, and $\gamma$ is the line joining $1$ to $i$.

I want to know the hint. How to calculate $f(z)$?

(The answer is $-\frac{2}{3}$).

Comment: How is a path integral defined?

Comment: It is just an ordinary line integral. If you parametrize the curve by $[0,1] \ni t \mapsto (1-t) + t i$, the integral becomes
$\int\limits_0^1 ((1-t)^2 + t^2 i)(-1 + i) dt$

Comment: It is impossible. You first need to specify a variable to integrate with respect to.

Comment: Well, I think this is a common notation as it is clear in respect to what we are integrating.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Substitute $y=1-x$ and calculate $$\int_{x=1}^{x=0}f(x,y)dz$$where $$dz=dx+idy=(1-i)dx\\f(x,y)=x^2+i(1-x)^2$$